# How to fire an event in Angular only when expansion panel is opened

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to reduce the number of network requests are sent by changing the event that triggers them. I only want the *fetchAvailableCompanies* http request to fire when the expansion panel is opened, not when the panel is closed.

Here's my component html:

```
 <mat-accordion *ngIf="modules">
    <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let module of modules">
      <mat-expansion-panel-header (click)="fetchAvailableCompanies(module.module_name)">
        <mat-panel-title>
          {{module.module_name}}
        </mat-panel-title>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <div *ngFor="let company of availableCompanies[module.module_name]">
        <mat-checkbox>{{company.name}}</mat-checkbox>
      </div>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
  </mat-accordion>
```

Instead of using on click, maybe I should do opened/expanded and closed/collapsed? Not sure how to implement that though. Also I'm planning on implementing caching of the http responses with Http Interceptors. Does this affect how I should approach this current issue?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

There is an event `afterExpand` for `mat-expansion-panel` (not the header):

```
<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let module of modules" (afterExpand)="fetchAvailableCompanies(module.module_name)">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
```